# save image to canvas then draw more

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

im trying to save a image to the canvas then draw more. this is what i got soo far. it spits out both my image and drawing but deletes the image when i add text

-

draw the image

```
var  tCtx2 = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
imageElem = document.getElementById('image');
var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
imageElem = document.getElementById('image');
var ttyl = document.getElementById('newimg');
tCtx2.drawImage(ttyl,0,0);
imageElem.src = tCtx2.canvas.toDataURL("images/image.png");
```

start text drawing

```
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function (){

tCtx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
var mytxt = document.getElementById('text').value;
var mystr1 = mytxt.substr(0, 31);
var mystr2 = mytxt.substr(31, 31);
var mystr3 = mytxt.substr(62, 31);
var mystr4 = mytxt.substr(93, 31);
tCtx.canvas.width = imageElem.width; 
tCtx.fillStyle = '#000000';
tCtx.font = '17pt "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif';
tCtx.fillText(mystr1, 10, 98); 
tCtx.fillText(mystr2, 10, 122);
tCtx.fillText(mystr3, 10, 146);
tCtx.fillText(mystr4, 10, 168);
```

start saving together

```
var copiedImg = new Image();
copiedImg.onload = function(){
tCtx.drawImage(copiedImg, 0, 0);
};

copiedImg.src = imageElem.src;


imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling it's this line:

```
tCtx.canvas.width = imageElem.width;
```

From [here](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/april/html5-canvas-how-to-clear-it.html):

> When you assign a value to the width or height poperties through
>   JavaScript it has the side effect of resetting the canvas. So
>   similarly to the clearRect function this means that the canvas is
>   returned to transparency.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Resizing the canvas element will clear the canvas contents. So Nato either will have to move resizing the canvas to before drawing the image or will have to move drawing the image to after the resizing.